# How to fix ghostscript path in python/pycharm [macOS]?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pycharm, python-imaging-library

As part of a larger program, I am trying to run the following code to save a gif from a tkinter-canvas-based animation using ghostscript and pyhton's PIL library:

```
images = []  #initialize blank queue to later save each frame of gif


def frame_save():
    # workaround function to save individual frame of tkinter-based animation to queue to later render/save as gif
    win.postscript(file="image.eps", colormode='color')
    img = NewImage.open("image.eps")
    images.append(img)


def save_gif(len):
    # function to render and save image queue as gif
    now = datetime.now()
    now_str = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    filename = f'SOLDR-L{survive_low}H{survive_high}E{exp}_{now_str}'
    images[0].save(f'{filename}.gif', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], optimize=False, duration=len*2, loop=0)
```

However, I get this error associated with the last code line above and ghostscript's subprocess.py in Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

The gs command *does* run when called from terminal or pycharm's shell, indicating ghostscript is successfully installed. Running 'which gs' in terminal returned the path '/opt/homebrew/bin/gs'. I tried adding the following line to the beginning of my code to fix PATH:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += ":/opt/homebrew/bin/gs"
```

However, I still get the same error traceback as before. I also tried a few terminal-command methods suggested online for fixing PATH to no avail. I am a beginner at programming and have a very limited knowledge of macOS terminal commands, etc., so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to add the path to **the containing directory** rather than to the actual executable itself. Try `os.environ["PATH"] += ":/opt/homebrew/bin`

Comment: that simple change seems to have done the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my comment as an answer so others can see it without needing to trawl through the comments...

You would need to add the path to the **containing directory** rather than to the actual **executable** itself, Try :

```
os.environ["PATH"] += ":/opt/homebrew/bin
```